# mariadb procedure for loop syntax

Tags: for-loop, stored-procedures, mariadb

Why those procedures does not produce the same results? Why I got error 1329?

```
CREATE TABLE TABA (A INT, B INT);
CREATE TABLE TABB (A INT, B INT);
INSERT INTO TABA VALUES (1, 11), (2, 22);
INSERT INTO TABB VALUES (1, 110), (2, 220);
```

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testa;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testa (IN tp1 INT)
 BEGIN
  FOR fp1 IN (SELECT TABA.A FROM TABA WHERE TABA.B LIKE tp1)
  DO
   SELECT * FROM TABB WHERE TABB.A LIKE fp1;
  END FOR;
 END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testb;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testb (IN tp1 INT)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE fp1 INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABA.A FROM TABA WHERE TABA.B LIKE tp1;
  OPEN cur1;
  loopa: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO fp1;
   SELECT * FROM TABB WHERE TABB.A LIKE fp1;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE cur1;
END; 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

```
CALL testa(11);
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

```
CALL testb(11);
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|    1 |  110 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

I thought to got a similar result. If I run the two SELECT statements manually they work.

Thanks

Comment: The SP syntax is arcane and antique.  Read the docs some more.

Comment: I already read some from MariaDB knowlegde-base. At the end I used cursor syntax, but I was curious to know how FOR loop works.

Comment: FOR is new in 10.3:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for/